# Xorg started in wrong GPU

Tags: xorg, nvidia, wayland

I have a system with two discrete GPUs, an nvidia one, which I use for playing and CUDA stuff, and an AMD one which I want to use to drive the desktop session. Displays are connected to the AMD card.

With this hardware, I am using Plasma session with Wayland, and apparently is running in the AMD card (not really sure how to check though), but `nvidia-smi` still shows that `/usr/lib/Xorg` is running on the nvidia card.

```
 nvidia-smi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ✔  20:36:15  
Sun Feb 26 20:38:22 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.89.02    Driver Version: 525.89.02    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:2D:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8    22W / 215W |      5MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1123      G   /usr/lib/Xorg                       4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would prefer to have Xwayland running on the AMD card. Also, I want to unload nvidia drivers on demand to be able to do passthrough to a VM, so having Xorg running on the nvidia card is unconvenient. How can I prevent that?